# Vagrant - launch using a private network

Tags: apache, vagrant, virtualbox

I tried to run private network using https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-install-apache-php-7-1-and-mysql-on-ubuntu-with-vagrant/

I am trying to start vagranta using a private network but I am getting this message:

```
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, and CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["hostonlyif", "create"]

Stderr: 0% ...
Progress state: E_FAIL
VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
VBoxManage.exe: error: SetupDiCreateDeviceInfo failed (0x00000005)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterfaceWrap, interface IHostNetworkInterface
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "enum RTEXITCODE __cdecl handleCreate (struct HandlerArg *)" at line 71 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp
```

I have a version right now:

vagrant Installed Version: 2.1.2
virtualbox 5.2.14

I`m using Windows 7

Here I am placing the config of my Vagrantfile:

```
# - * - mode: ruby ​​- * -
# vi: set ft = ruby:

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (in support of the old styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please do not change it unless you know what
# you're doing.
Vagrant.configure (2) do | config |
  # The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
  # For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
  # boxes at https://atlas.hashicorp.com/search.
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu / xenial64"

  # Disable automatic box update checking. If you disable this, then
  # boxes will be running for updates
  # `vagrant box outdated`. This is not recommended.
  # config.vm.box_check_update = false

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost: 8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080

  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  # using a specific IP.
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

  # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
  # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
  # your network.
  # config.vm.network "public_network"

  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # the path on the actual folder. The second argument is
  # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
  # argument is a set of non-required options.
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www/html"

  # Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
  # backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
  # Example for VirtualBox:
  #
  # config.vm.provider "virtualbox" to | vb |
  # # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
  # vb.gui = true
  #
  # # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
  # vb.memory = "1024"
  # end
  #
  # View the documentation for the provider you are using for more
  # information on available options.

  # Define a Vagrant Push strategy for pushing to Atlas. Other push strategies
  # such as FTP and Heroku are also available. See the documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/push/atlas.html for more information.
  # config.push.define "atlas" to | push |
  # push.app = "YOUR_ATLAS_USERNAME / YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME"
  # end

  # Enable provisioning with a shell script. Additional provisioners such as
  # Puppet, Chef, Ansible, Salt, and Docker are also available. Please see the
  # documentation for more information about their specific syntax and use.
  # config.vm.provision "shell", inline: << - SHELL
  # sudo apt-get update
  # sudo apt-get install -y apache2
  # SHELL
end
```

I've added to Vagrantfile and private_network:

```
name: "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter", auto_config: false
```

Error not showing but cant see website. If you want more details please ask I will try show it.

Can this apply to rights? I try to run it on my company computer.

Comment: I`m still have this problem any ideas about this ?

Comment: I thought the problem was the lack of administrator rights